# Comma in the output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote a function that considers the height and width of the div , now I can not find where I wrote the code,that output value with comma
example: #div_0{ height: 13.3%;**,** width: 28.5%; }

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.percent = function (el, arg2) {
        var pol = $(this).parent()

        if (typeof (el) != 'object') {
            if (typeof (el) == 'number' && arg2 == 'w' || typeof (el) == 'number' && arg2 == 'width') return el * 100 / parseInt(pol.css('width'))+ '%;' ;
            else if (typeof (el) == 'number' && arg2 == 'h' || typeof (el) == 'number' && arg2 == 'height') return el * 100 / parseInt(pol.css('height'))+ '%;';
            else return false;
        }
        var set = [];
        for (var i in el) {
            var element = parseInt($(this).css(i));
            if (el[i] == 'w' || el[i] == 'width') set[set.length] = '\n' + i + ': ' + element * 100 / parseInt(pol.css('width'))+ '%;' ;
            else if (el[i] == 'h' || el[i] == 'height') set[set.length] = '\n' + i + ': ' + element * 100 / parseInt(pol.css('height'))+ '%;';
        }
        return set; 
    }
})(jQuery);

var return_ = '';
var sharp = '#';

function chet_div() {
    for (var i = 0; i < $('#container div').length; i++) {
        if ($('#container div').eq(i).attr('id').search(/div/i) != -1) {
            return_ += sharp + $('#container div').eq(i).attr('id') + '{\n ' + $('#container div').eq(i).percent({ height: 'h', width: 'w' }) + '\n}\n';
        }
        document.getElementById('hidden_sizes').value = return_;
    }
    return return_;
}
```

Thank

Comment: Are you asking us to debug the code you wrote?

Comment: @Vld Yes(i and my friend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function `percent()` returns an array so but used inside a string so it uses `toString()` method which joins values with coma

```
.percent({ height: 'h', width: 'w' })
```

I'd recommend to use it as below instead

```
.percent({ height: 'h', width: 'w' }).join("")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin constructs an array of CSS rules and returns this array:

```
var set = [];
// ...
return set;
```

Later you concatenate this array with some strings:

```
'{\n ' + $('#container div').eq(i).percent({
    height: 'h',
    width: 'w'
}) + '\n}\n';
```

In this case array will be converted to String type as well with its `toString` method. Now, `toString` for Array calles [`join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) internally, which uses `,` as a default separator. This is a reason why you see ','.

To overcome the problem don't rely on implicit type casting that happens in this case, but create a string yourself with correct separator:

```
'{\n ' + $('#container div').eq(i).percent({
    height: 'h',
    width: 'w'
}).join('') + '\n}\n';
```